# KAFKA: Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.tools.StorageTool

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to prepare my Kafka by following the quickstart: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart 
I'm trying to do the Step 2: Start the Kafka environment with KRaft:

[image]

So I tried to put the `KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID="$(bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)"` to the Bash in the Kafka root folder and got following error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, the root folder of it is on Desktop and I renamed it to `kafka` (removed the versions from name). I did `cd kafka`, so it moved me into kafka root level. And java which I use is 8. 
I was also trying it even with the name with the versions and I also tried to put the folder right under C: - didn't help.

Comment: it definitively has problems running on Windows - I got `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \tmp\kafka\bin\..\config\tools-log4j.properties` despite the file being there and being readable, but note the ``\`` - backslashes should not be used for *nix or similar - in my case I suppose the problem is because it is using the WIndows Java (despite being in a *nix (simulated?) environment)

Comment: This helped. Thank you for your time.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-run-apache-kafka-on-windows/
Closing the ticket.